# Is it possible to run Expo using EAS on an iPhone device but on Windows?

Tags: react-native, expo

I've being using Expo for a couple years now, but I always use the Expo Go app to run my app locally and also publishing updates. Right now, most of the libraries are only supported when using [development builds](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/use-development-builds/), and this is making me consider moving out from Expo Go to use development builds.

The big issue here is that I don't have a Mac, and I also don't want to work on a Mac, I just can't get used to the OS and the keyboard, so I want to keep working on Windows but I want to run my app locally on my iPhone.

As far as I understand, I have to build the native dependencies in order to run the build local, but of course that won't work for the iOS app, since I'm working on windows. But maybe it's possible to generate that build using EAS and still run the app on my iPhone device, but I'm not sure about that.

So the question is, is it possible to run my app locally (during development, so I expect fast refresh and debug tools) on windows but using an iPhone device without the need of a Mac?

Comment: [Create EAS build](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/) You can create development build using EAS to build apps in the Cloud, and download the build to the device. For local build you need to have a Xcode and mac.

Comment: So it's not possible at all to run my code on Windows during development while testing in my iPhone? Right now, using the Expo Go app this is possible, I just want to do the same but with a development build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use EAS for development builds. Once built and installed on your device it can connect to any remote development server, no matter which OS it’s running on.

You can read more about how to create and install a dev build in the official documentation [here](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/)

Comment: If you read my question at the end, I want to know if it's possible to use a development build running on my iPhone device but while coding on a Windows OS. I want to know if I will have fast refresh and other debug tools while coding. Please, read the question before answering

Comment: Of course that is possible. The dev server and the development client are unrelated. This is unrelated to EAS or development builds.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. If you please update your answer and include some steps on how to do this, I will accept the answer

Comment: I have updated my answer. The link I initially added includes all the steps necessary